# How to assert multiple elements values in a form using Xpath Assertion in Jmeter?

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I'm trying to assert some text-fields values in a form
and I can only assert on a single one through Xpath Assertion post-processor.
How can I assert the whole form fields within a single http sampler ?

I tried to assert multiple text-fields in a single "Xpath Assertion" component, but it didn't work.
Here a couple of fields I'm trying to assert in a single Xpath Assertion component:

```
//*[@class='ProjectNameInput']/@value='Dummy_Project'
//*[@class='Desc2']/@value='Dummy_Desc'[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a simple approach using xpath. As you are expecting all the fields in a form you can write the xpath to get the form element if it have all the required value elements.

For example in the SO question when you click on `Add Comment` (right below your question). That comment text area,Add Comment button and help button are part of the form. I want to verify if all those elements are present with the given text. Then I can use below xpath.
[image: sample xpath on Stack Overflow page]

So in your case you can do something like this.

```
//form[.//xpath_of_first_element and .//xpath_of_2nd_element and .//xpath_of_3rd_element]
```

Make sure you specify the `.//` in the `[]` otherwise it will check the entire page rather under the form.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this everywhere, could not find it. Was hesitating about using 2 XPath Assertions nearby, so glad finding that your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Going forward consider adding at least partial or better full page [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) to your question, the chance of getting a comprehensive answer will be much higher.

In the meantime, given you have following [HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="ProjectNameInput" value="Dummy_Project"/>
    <input type="text" class="Desc2" value="Dummy_Desc"/>
</form>
```

you can use the following [XPath expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) in order to match 2 nested [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tags:

```
//form[./input[@class='ProjectNameInput']/@value='Dummy_Project' and ./input[@class='Desc2']/@value='Dummy_Desc']
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/)